# Support App Deeplinking on clicking on the link shared from my app to any social app

Tags: android, meta-tags, deep-linking

I want to support `deeplinking` on clicking on the link shared in any social app. There is a separate steps to support deeplinking from `facebook, twitter and Google +`. There might be  support available for some other apps, but not for all the apps. I want to make it generic. Is there a way to that. I must use meta tags for deeplinking. But for deeplinking, `twitter` has used `googleplay` and `facebook` has used `al:android:url` to detect our app. If I want to support for other apps , I must use similar tags like this. Does anyone know how this can be achieved ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

...and to make matters worse, Facebook doesn't really support their own AppLinks standard anymore, Google uses two totally different systems depending on whether you're using the standalone Chrome browser or not, and App Links (yes, they're different from AppLinks) are now a thing. You're right: app deep linking is an incredible, huge pain to implement and there truly is no 'generic' option at the moment.

This is why [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure, in case it wasn't obvious by now: I'm on the team) exists. We wrap all of these different standards into a single free service, so that all you worry about is one URL that works everywhere. It's the closest you can get to a 'generic standard' with the current realities.